# Does removing the intercept from linear regression reduce the bias from the predictor MSE?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

This is a deceptively simple question but one that, to the best of my knowledge, has no good proof/answer online. If anyone can point to a source please do, because I failed to find any.

The question is: if we remove the intercept from a linear regression model, does it reduce the bias component of the MSE (Mean squared error)?

Comment: Is there a bias in an ordinary linear regression model (with intercept)?

Comment: No, I think this is what I am basically proving.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have 2 simple linear regression models $M_1$ and $M_2$, each described by the following model equations

$$M_1: Y = \beta_1 X + \beta_0 + \epsilon $$
$$M_2: Y = \beta_2 X + \epsilon $$

In plain English, $M_1$ is a linear regression with the intercept, and $M_2$ is a linear regression without the intercept for some set of data $\{X_1, X_2, \dots X_n\}$ and $\{Y_1, Y_2, \dots Y_n\}$.

We can write the predictors of $Y$ for the 2 models as

$$\hat{Y}_{1,i} = \hat{\beta_1} X_i + \hat{\beta_0}$$
$$\hat{Y}_{2,i} = \hat{\beta_2} X_i $$

Note that in the general case absolutely nothing implies that $\hat{\beta_1} = \hat{\beta_2}$ or that they are even "close". Please check [this answer to a related question on stack overflow which provides a nice visual depiction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26205/34578)

As per the definition of Mean Squared Error (MSE) and Bias for predictors and the expression for $\hat{\beta_0} = \bar{Y} - \bar{X}\hat{\beta_1}$, we can write

$$ Bias(\hat{Y}_{1,i}) = (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{Y}_{1,i} - Y_i))^2 = (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{\beta_1} X_i + \hat{\beta_0} - Y_i))^2 = (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{\beta_1} X_i + \bar{Y} - \bar{X}\hat{\beta_1} - Y_i))^2  =  (\hat{\beta_1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X}) + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{Y} - Y_i))^2 = 0 $$

This is consistent with the usual definition of linear regression (with intercept) being "an unbiased estimator".

We also have

$$ Bias(\hat{Y}_{2,i}) = (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{Y}_{2,i} - Y_i))^2 = (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{\beta_2} X_i - Y_i))^2 \geq 0 $$

So unless we are in a degenerate case i.e. all $X_i = Y_i$ we can conclude that $Bias(\hat{Y}_{2,i}) > Bias(\hat{Y}_{1,i}) = 0$

Hence, removing the intercept from a linear regression model will in general **increase** the bias term in the MSE. We have not proved anything for the full MSE though: we would need to analyse the variance term.

Comment: Since the intercept is usually called "bias" this result is rather unintuitive or paradoxical at first. One possible interpration is that by removing the intercept, we are reducing the model parameters by 1, which should "increase bias". Another is that we are forcing the line to go through the origin (0,0) which is an extra constraint hence the model is more "biased".

Comment: Why do you compute bias in terms of the sample average instead of the expectation? Also, whether or not OLS estimator is unbiased depends on your model assumptions (e.g. strict exogeneity)

Comment: Since I treat it as "predictor MSE" vs "estimator MSE" c.f wikipedia article on MSE. I think in this case it will work out the same. I also really only care about the sample case from a practical pov